# How to implement a meta-circular evaluator to parse `[1..10]` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, metacircular

I want to implement a meta-circular evaluator in JS with support to functional programming.

How can I parse this?

`[1..10]`

I want to receive 1 and 10

Comment: `const [min, max] = "[1..10]".match(/\[(\d+)\.\.(\d+)\]/).slice(1).map(Number)`

Comment: _"I want to implement a meta-circular evaluator in JS with support to functional programming"_ ... probably regex will not be sufficient for this task. I suggest writing a grammar and using a parser like antlr. You may use small regexes of some flavor or other to the grammar to tokenize, but that's implementation-specific depending on the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic implementation of generating a range.
The goal you are talking about is going to be [too complex for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (firmly tongue in cheek).

Using [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax.
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/BXbDF3/1) finds two digit sequences, converts to numbers.  Fills an array.

```js
range = (str,...args) =>
(([,min,max])=>
  Array(Math.abs(max-min)+1).fill(+min).map((_,i)=>_+i*(min>max?-1:1)))
    ((Array.isArray(str) ? str.map((s,i)=>s+args[i]).join('') : str)
      .match(/\[\s*(-?\d+)\s*\.\.\s*(-?\d+)\s*\]/))

x=-3, y=0
console.log(
range`[5..1]`,
range`[1..10]`,
range("[ 5 .. -2 ]"),
range`[${x}.. ${y}]`
)
```

Comment: I was going to ask what does a tagged template function offer that a regular function doesn't if you're not leveraging the args array? As far as I can see you're rebuilding a string out of it. You could _simply_ assume that if `str` is an array then `args[0]` is `min` and `args[1]` is `max`. Otherwise fallback to the regex.

Comment: That's true.  I really only meant this as a toy function just to show basic extraction using the regex, and a reasonably easy to read syntax for creating the range (2nd nicer than 3rd).  Probably won't even end up being used by OP :\  Probably if you really wanted something like this, I'd think you'd go for an iterable convertable range object and/or generator, JS syntax ought to be plenty expressive enough (you might even be able to simulate `..` directly using some kind of getter on the Number prototype)?  And for actual syntax parsing of your language in a string use a grammar parser.

Answer (score 2):

I've been longing to try out [nearley.js](https://nearley.js.org/docs/index) for so long. This may or may not be what you wanted!

---

*Please do note that I have assumed that what you want to get out of `[1..10]` is all the numbers from `1` to `10` (included), e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.*

---

**Let's define the grammar for this mini language**

*grammar.ne*

```
# Given the string "[1..10]", AST is ['[', 1, '..', 10, ']']
# We define a postprocessor that immediately interprets the expression
range -> "[" number ".." number "]" {%
  function range(ast) {
    const [,a,,b,] = ast; // extracts the number from the ast
    const len = Math.abs(a - b) + 1;
    const inc = a < b ? (_, i) => a + i : (_, i) => a - i;
    return Array.from(Array(len), inc);
  }
%}

# Given the string "1", AST is [['1']]
# Given the string "10", AST is [['1','0']]
# We define a postprocessor that joins the characters together and coerce them into a number.
number -> [0-9]:+ {% ([chars]) => Number(chars.join('')) %}
```

What I like about nearley.js is that it allows you to embed post processors for your rules *right* into the grammar. It *may* looks ugly but I find it pretty neat actually!

Another cool thing, is that nearley.js comes with a suite of useful tools. One of them generates a diagram for your grammar:

```
yarn run -s nearley-railroad grammar.ne > grammar.html
```

Here's the output:

As you can see a range is a sequence of:

1. Starts with `"["`
2. Followed by a number
3. Followed by `".."`
4. Followed by a number
5. Ends with `"]"`

[image]

**Now we need to compile that grammar**

```
yarn run -s nearleyc grammar.ne > grammar.js
```

This code needs to be loaded into a parser. I'm just showing the compiled grammar for illustration purpose:

*grammar.js*

```js
// Generated automatically by nearley, version 2.19.3
// http://github.com/Hardmath123/nearley
(function () {
function id(x) { return x[0]; }
var grammar = {
    Lexer: undefined,
    ParserRules: [
    {"name": "range$string$1", "symbols": [{"literal":"."}, {"literal":"."}], "postprocess": function joiner(d) {return d.join('');}},
    {"name": "range", "symbols": [{"literal":"["}, "number", "range$string$1", "number", {"literal":"]"}], "postprocess": 
        function range(ast) {
          const [,a,,b,] = ast; // extracts the number from the ast
          const len = Math.abs(a - b) + 1;
          const inc = a < b ? (_, i) => a + i : (_, i) => a - i;
          return Array.from(Array(len), inc);
        }
        },
    {"name": "number$ebnf$1", "symbols": [/[0-9]/]},
    {"name": "number$ebnf$1", "symbols": ["number$ebnf$1", /[0-9]/], "postprocess": function arrpush(d) {return d[0].concat([d[1]]);}},
    {"name": "number", "symbols": ["number$ebnf$1"], "postprocess": ([chars]) => Number(chars.join(''))}
]
  , ParserStart: "range"
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined'&& typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
   module.exports = grammar;
} else {
   window.grammar = grammar;
}
})();
```

**Now let's build a parser and use it!**

*index.js*

```js
const nearley = require("nearley");
const grammar = require("./grammar"); // loads the compiled grammar!

const parser = new nearley.Parser(nearley.Grammar.fromCompiled(grammar));

parser.feed("[1..10]");

console.log(parser.results[0]);
//=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `\[([0-9]+)\.\.([0-9]+)\]`

I confirmed the regex via regex101.com and let it generate the sample code.

```js
const regex = /\[([0-9]+)\.\.([0-9]+)\]/gm;
const str = `[1..10]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Result:

```
Found match, group 0: 1..10
Found match, group 1: 1
Found match, group 2: 10
```